# Converting String to System.guid c#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am trying to retrieve a client's name based on the Account GUID, using sql and c#.

```
static DataClasses1DataContext dbDataClasses = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var accountList = from accounts in dbDataClasses.ACCOUNTs where   accounts.AccountGUID.ToString() = "e8d82d5d-b7bd-4b24-a7fe-ef050921e960"
                          select accounts;

        foreach (ACCOUNT temp in accountList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Account Name: " + temp.Name + " Account GUID: " + temp.AccountGUID);
        }

    }
```

However, I receive an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.guid'

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [Guid.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse.aspx)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to convert the Guid to string before comparing to a string:

```
var accountList = from accounts in dbDataClasses.ACCOUNTs where accounts.AccountGUID.ToString()== "e8d82d5d"
```

However "e8d82d5d" is not a guid, so you will never see any results from this query.

Comment: var accountList = from accounts in dbDataClasses.ACCOUNTs where accounts.AccountGUID.ToString() = "e8d82d5d-b7bd-4b24-a7fe-ef050921e960"
I've edited my code with the code above, but now I get an error saying I can't convert to bool?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [documentation for the `Guid` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx). There's a constructor that takes a `string` and there's also the `Parse` static method

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Guid.Parse()
```

or `Guid.ParseExact()`
on your string before using it in :

```
where accounts.AccountGUID= "e8d82d5d"
```

it should be like :

```
 where accounts.AccountGUID= Guid.Parse("e8d82d5d")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can do it

**Assuming all Id's are in a valid format**

```
Guid accountId = Guid.Parse(accountIdString);
```

assumes that your accountIdString is always in a validated format, and if it isn't it will throw an exception

**Assuming Id's might be in an invalid format**

```
Guid accountId;
bool parseCheck = Guid.TryParse(accountIdString, out accountId);
```

will attempt to parse your accountIdString, and return true or false to parseCheck based on whether it succeeded or not.  If it succeeded it will also store the parsed Guid as accountId

Which one you use depends on if you know every Id is in valid Guid format or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
static DataClasses1DataContext dbDataClasses = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Guid someGuid;
        if(Guid.TryParse("e8d82d5d", out someGuid))
        {
             var accountList = from accounts in dbDataClasses.ACCOUNTs where accounts.AccountGUID= someGuid
                          select accounts;

            foreach (ACCOUNT temp in accountList)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Account Name: " + temp.Name + " Account GUID: " + temp.AccountGUID);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //error handle
        }


   }
```